# How to set my Konva fillPatternImage 100% height

Tags: reactjs, canvas, konvajs

I'm using [Konva](https://konvajs.github.io/) (in React).

```
  <Rect
    x={x}
    y={y}
    width={width}
    height={height}
    ...
    fillPatternImage={this.state.image}
    fillPatternRepeat="repeat-x"
  />
```

The [fill image](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/styling/Fill.html) is showing, repeating but it height is the initial height of my source image. I would like to "fit" it with my shape (kind of height 100% / Y cover).

There is lot of feature on [the doc](https://konvajs.github.io/api/Konva.Rect.html) (fillPatternX, fillPatternOffsetX, fillPatternScaleX) but no one is looking for what I want.

How can I do ?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you want to see as a result? Probably `fillPatternScaleY` will work for you.

Comment: I'm using a transformer. I want that my fill cover the area (100% 100%) during the transformation.

Comment: Can you make an online demo of what you already have?

Comment: first I will try with ScaleY, I think you are right. If it's not working, I will make a fiddle :).

Comment: @lavrton You were right !! fillPatternScaleY={height / patternImageHeight}. If you want to add the answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fillPatternScaleX` and `fillPatternScaleY` to scale pattern image into required size. You may need to know the original image size of your pattern to calculate the scale.

`fillPatternScaleY={requiredHeight / patternImageHeight}`